# Opening a chroot'd process in PHP

Tags: php, chroot, proc-open

I have a PHP script that needs to execute more than a few commands in a chroot. So far, I have just been doing this:

```
exec( 'sudo chroot --userspec=user /path/to/chroot /path/to/command', $output );
```

However, I'm starting to wonder if executing this so many times is really the most efficient way to do things. Perhaps something more like this:

```
$p = exec( 'sudo chroot --userspec=user /path/to/chroot /bin/bash' );
```

And then:

```
exec( $p, '/path/to/command', $output );
```

Obviously I know this won't work. I've been looking at `proc_open` for a while now and it seemed promising, but I can't get it to work for me.

I would like to execute each command, and then capture its return value and any output on stdout.

Am I wasting my time, or is there an appropriate way to implement this?

Comment: you'd need to chroot the whole PHP process

Comment: Shoot. Unfortunately that isn't an option the way I've got things set up. I would actually need to open multiple chroots, and it's running through FPM (as a privileged user).

Comment: same new root, or different each time?

Comment: maybe you can use proc_open

Comment: I was able to pipe commands in and get output out, but stream blocking/nonblocking made it tricky, plus I couldn't get return values. I would need to open a few chroots, and then execute several commands in each one.